# while loop returning same date value even after adding a day each time - c#

Tags: c#

Am I doing something very silly here, fromDate value always remains what has been passed.

```
public List<String> GetDates(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
    List<String> Dates = new List<String>();
    while (fromDate <= toDate)
    {
        Dates.Add(fromDate.ToShortDateString());
        fromDate.AddDays(1);
    }
    return Dates;
}
```

I can't figure out why, Please advise.

Comment: Your post missing link to MSDN article for `DateTime.AddDays` and explanation what you don't understand from it, or maybe links to top couple result from search like https://www.bing.com/search?q=DateTime.AddDays with corresponding explanations what additional information is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to assign to `fromDate`, [`AddDays()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not modify the instance on which it is called:

```
fromDate = fromDate.AddDays(1);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the method description of `.AddDays`, you'll see that it actually returns a datetime object, it does not actually modify the variable in which AddDays is being called.

You can get your desired behavior by:

```
fromDate = fromDate.AddDays(1);
```

See more info at:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The [MSDN Help for AddDays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) has the following sentence worth noting, towards the end of the page under "Remarks":

> This method does not change the value of this DateTime. Instead, it
>   returns a new DateTime whose value is the result of this operation.

Simply store the returned DateTime object and you are good to go.

```
fromDate = fromDate.AddDays(1);
```